# Error starting Tomcat context after adding spring-boot-starter-data-redis in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, redis, project-reactor, lettuce

```
2020-01-09 14:20:15.213 ERROR 7694 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.redis.RedisHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lettuceClientResources' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources]: Factory method 'lettuceClientResources' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers
2020-01-09 14:20:15.238  INFO 7694 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-01-09 14:20:15.247  WARN 7694 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2020-01-09 14:20:15.259  INFO 7694 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-01-09 14:20:15.267 ERROR 7694 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.infotmt.nobilis.nobilisenterprise.Application.main(Application.java:41) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:427) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.redis.RedisHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lettuceClientResources' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources]: Factory method 'lettuceClientResources' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:235) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:226) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:261) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:455) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.redis.RedisHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lettuceClientResources' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources]: Factory method 'lettuceClientResources' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthIndicatorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicatorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthIndicatorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.redis.RedisHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'redisConnectionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lettuceClientResources' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultClientResources]: Factory method 'lettuceClientResources' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean(EndpointDiscoverer.java:149) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:136) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:119) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:76) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4c0cf10.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4c0cf10$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c0eb2c65.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4c0cf10.servletEndpointRegistrar(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

The main error showing are:

Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException:Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cachesEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/cache/CachesEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cachesEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [com/infotmt/nobilis/nobilisenterprise/config/CacheConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/infotmt/nobilis/nobilisenterprise/config/CacheConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cachesEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/cache/CachesEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cachesEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [com/infotmt/nobilis/nobilisenterprise/config/CacheConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/infotmt/nobilis/nobilisenterprise/config/CacheConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cachesEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/cache/CachesEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cachesEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [com/infotmt/nobilis/nobilisenterprise/config/CacheConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/infotmt/nobilis/nobilisenterprise/config/CacheConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManager' defined in class path resource [com/infotmt/nobilis/nobilisenterprise/config/CacheConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cacheManager' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/infotmt/nobilis/nobilisenterprise/config/CacheConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/infotmt/nobilis/nobilisenterprise/config/CacheConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers

Comment: I found the problem is with the reactor-core and letteuce-core version. I am using reactor-core version:2.0.8:RELEASE. The jedis is using lettuce-core:5.2.1.RELEASE version. For lettuce-core it requires 3.x version of reactor-core. Is there any solution if i don't want to upgrade to reactor-core version?

Comment: No sensible options as far as I'm aware other than upgrading reactor.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with java used in eclipse.
Installed JRE was using default which came with STS /Eclipse.
I changed it to use JDK 1.8 installed on my system.
It worked immediately.